# Get part of django model depending on a variable

Tags: django, python-3.x

## My code

```
PriceListItem.objects.get(id=tarif_id).price_eur
```

## In my settings.py

`CURRENCY='eur'`

## My Question:

I would like to pick the different info depending on the CURRENCY variable in `settings.py`

## Example:

```
  PriceListItem.objects.get(id=tarif_id).price_+settings.CURRENCY
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. This has nothing to do with Django actually. You can reach the instance's attribute through pure Python:

```
getattr(PriceListItem.objects.get(id=tarif_id), 'price_'+settings.CURRENCY)
```

Note it might be a better idea to have a method on the model which accepts the currency as a parameter and returns the correct piece of data (through the line I wrote above, for example).

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work

```
item = PriceListItem.objects.get(id=tarif_id)
value = getattr(item, price_+settings.CURRENCY)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are only interested in that *specific* column, you can make the query more efficient with `.values_list`:

```
my_price = PriceListItem.objects.values_list_(
    'price_{}'.format(settings.CURRENCY),
    flat=True
).get(id=tarif_id)
```

This will only fetch that specific column from the database, which can be a (a bit) faster than first fetching the entire row into memory, and then discard all the rest later.

Here `my_price` is thus *not* a `PriceListItem` object, but the value that is stored for the specific `price_cur` column.

It will thus result in a query that looks like:

```
SELECT pricelistitem.price_cur
FROM pricelistitem
WHERE id=tarif_id
```